# linker command failed with exit code 1 when building Unity project in Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unity-game-engine

Im trying to build an iOS application developed with Unity. The app builds and runs just fine on Android as an apk or aab.
When building for iOS I get no errors in Unity and the Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj and Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace are built. I open the Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace and make sure the signing of the app is well and all.
But when trying to archive the project i get these errors :

(these errors appears during the building of the UnityFramework and are associated with it)

- `ld: warning: Could not find or use auto-linked library 'swiftCoreMIDI'`
- `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7`
- `clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1`
- `Undefined symbol: _swiftoverride_class_getSuperclass(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*)`
- `Undefined symbol: swift::swift51override_conformsToSwiftProtocol(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, llvm::StringRef, swift::TargetProtocolConformanceDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const* (*)(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, llvm::StringRef))`

Additionnal informations :

- Im using Unity 2019.3.6f1 and I made sure to go in the iOS Resolver settings and checked the "**Podfile Generation**", "**Auto Install Cocoapod Tools in Editor**" and "**Use project settings**" to true as well as setting the Cocoapods Integration to "**Xcode Workspace - Add Cocoapods to the Xcode workspace**"
- I also make sure to open the Unity-iPhone.xcworkspace and not the Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj.
- I use Xcode 12.0.1 with Swift 5.3 and Im targeting iOS 10.0
- My version of cocoapod is 1.8.4.

Things I have tried :

- Adding the "*swiftCoreMIDI*" library to the list of *Frameworks and Libraries* and/or the list *Link Binary With Libraries* in the UnityFramework's build phase.
- Adding *DEAD_CODE_STRIPPING = NO* to the build settings of the target UnityFramework.
- Installing Xcode 5.0 and using it from the toolchain menu of Xcode to build.
- In Unity's player settings, setting the Architecture to *Universal*, *ARM64* and *ARMv7*.
- Using *"Symlink Unity libraries"* in Unity's build options
- Reduce/Increase the build target to 8.0 / 12.0
- And many other things that I cant recall at the moment... (been stuck on this for days)

none of these attempts removed or changed the errors.

As I understand the problem is that a library inside the *UnityFramework* is trying to call some functions in the "*swiftCoreMIDI*" library but cannot access them. But i cant figure out why adding the library to the list of *Frameworks and Libraries* in the general panel and/or the list *Link Binary With Libraries* in the UnityFramework's build phase doesnt solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for any ideas or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution, it was linked to the UnityFramework target in Xcode. I had to remove some architectures that are not concerned by my build: i386 and x86_64. In addition, I updated the Library Search Paths to include $(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift.

To execute those actions automatically, you can add those lines in a PostProcessBuild file in your Unity project:

```
var projPath = pathToBuiltProject + "/Unity-iPhone.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj";
var proj = new PBXProject();
proj.ReadFromFile(projPath);

// Update the Library Search Paths of the whole Xcode project
proj.AddBuildProperty(proj.ProjectGuid(), "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS", "$(SDKROOT)/usr/lib/swift");

// Get the UnityFramework target and exclude the unwanted architectures
var unityFrameworkGuid = proj.TargetGuidByName("UnityFramework");
proj.SetBuildProperty(unityFrameworkGuid, "EXCLUDED_ARCHS", "i386");
proj.AddBuildProperty(unityFrameworkGuid, "EXCLUDED_ARCHS", "x86_64");
```